# elasticsearch-php, google like search with fix for spelling errors

Tags: php, elasticsearch

I am building an E-commerce project with demo database of products, brands and vendors.I have implemented auto suggest in search bar,it works.
what I am unable to do is fix for spelling errors. For eg-if a user search for Motorola as motoroal no results is given.
Can anybody point me to right direction?

Answer (score 0):

That's not a easy task.

I use the following setup:

```
'analysis' => [
    'filter' => [
        'nGram_filter' => [
            'type' => 'edgeNGram',
            'min_gram' => '1',
            'max_gram' => '20',
            'token_chars' => [
                'letter',
                'digit',
                'punctuation',
                'symbol',
            ],
        ],
    ],
    'analyzer' => [
        'nGram_analyzer' => [
            'type' => 'custom',
            'tokenizer' => 'whitespace',
            'filter' => [
                'lowercase',
                'asciifolding',
                'nGram_filter',
            ],
        ],
    ]
]
```

Then I set my fields map to use the `nGram_analyzer` as `analyzer`.

The [`edgeNGram`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-edgengram-tokenizer.html) tokenizer will break your words in this way:

`motorola` will be break into: `m mo mot moto motor motoro motorol motorola`

This setup will act like an *auto complete*, predicting what your user is trying to search.

To help with spelling errors, you will need to apply some similar analyzer to the `search_analyzer` on your field mapping.

Comment: i have already implemented Auto complete ,can you give an example of search_analyzer?

Comment: The search analyzer do the same as the analyzer, but with the query itself. For example, if I do a `NGram` on `motorpla`, it will break in many pieces, one of them `motor`, other `la`. Searching for this terms will probably bring the `motorola` result.